# Convert a python-lists to a dataframein r

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

In my R code, a python server returns 2 lists :

For example: `columns = ['a','b','c']` and `Values = ['mode','median','0']`

How can I convert this list to a vector in R? Or convert both of them into a `data.frame` in R?

I want something like

```
col <- c('a','b','c')
val <- c('mode','median','0')
```

I want to use these as:

```
df <- data.frame(Column_Name = col, value = val)
```

Comment: One way I could think of, what if you save them as CSV and then read it the way you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "In my R code, a python server returns 2 lists"? How do you call a python process from R? Using a particular package? System call?

Comment: This code is in a RMarkdown report- used in a separate tool, not the typical Rstudio. In this tool, i can connect python code to this report

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer:-
R reads the result I get from python code as a string as given below:-

```
columns = "['a','b','c']"
```

So to convert the above into a vector/dataframe following can be done:-

```
a <- data.frame(Col_Name = unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]|\\'",'',columns),',')))
```

The above code returns a data frame as:-

```
Col_name
a
b
c
d
```

Similar process can be done for "Values" and converted into a dataframe